# Squash tools don't make correct image for use

Tags: boot, xubuntu, squashfs

I want to modify few files on Xubuntu 14.04 LTS Live CD, because I'd like to use it for netboot. I need to change a file that starts some service and that's all. I already looked on internet for tutorials which would be appropriate for my needs, but everything I tried so far, didn't work well.

Basically I used these two pages as base for all my actions:

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/80305/mounting-a-squashfs-filesystem-in-read-write
- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization

The first thing I've done, was to run `unsquashfs` on filesystem.squashfs located in casper directory. I got image which I modified a little bit and then I used `mksquashfs` without additional flags, to create new squashfs image. After all I updated filesystem.size (also located in casper dir) and md5sum.txt (located in root of ISO). I tried to boot like before and something went wrong, because I got only to a console saying something about ...

> (initramfs): For more information use 'help' command

... and that was it. Afterwards I've done complete procedure again, but without file modification like before. The result is the same as above and I don't know what am I doing wrong. There is no any error message nowhere, I just get to initramfs console at the end.

I would really appreciate any help, because right now I'm out of ideas how to solve that problem. Thank you very much in advance!